# Do private domains names really hide owner information?

Tags: networking, dns, hosting

I want to register a domain name in order to do political activism. I want to hide my personal information from being displayed. For that I'm considering registering a provide domain from a website like godaddy.com

My question: how safe is that? Can anyone access the private personal information of the owner of the domain?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hosting companies.


Comment: Nobody said it yet? Ok, I will. ***GODADDY STINKS!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [arin](https://www.arin.net/resources/restful-interfaces.html) your contact information will be availble in customer records but not to Whois users. If somebody gets access to the customer records then they can access your contact information. Whether this can happen depends on service provider policies and also dpends on the laws of the country where your service provider is situated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [privacyprotect.org](http://privacyprotect.org/about-privacyprotection/)
for free to hide your contact information. read on the link for more info on how it works and how safe it is.